# SVG Not Showing in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, svg

Edit #1: Here's the code I put in functions.php:

```
function my_myme_types($mime_types){
    $mime_types['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml'; //Adding svg extension
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1);
```

Edit #2:

Here's my code to input it:

```
<img src="http://localhost/webdesign/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Web-Design.svg" />
```

I've edited my functions.php file so I can upload SVG images ([here's](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-additional-file-types-to-be-uploaded-in-wordpress/) the article).  So after I did that, I was able to link SVG files and I could see them.  However, I went to take a nap, and when I came back, the SVG files never showed up.  I could link them, but it was a white screen, and when I right-click to view image, it's just white, too.

Does anyone know what could be doing this?  I've made a second localhost Wordpress website, and the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. The point is, you have to give that image a `width` and a `height` in order to make it visible.

Here is an example: Go to http://geigerag.ch/ ... there is a logo on the top in svg. As you may see, the logo has a width of 325px and a height of auto. Try to remove those values or try to right click on that image to view it in a new tab. However, the image will be blank.

Comment: I did give them the values; however, it's still not showing.

Comment: @ThomasHutton could you please upload the svg somewhere, so I can test it?

Comment: Hmmm, so when I use that URL it works, but not on my local file.

Comment: @ThomasHutton hmm ... how does your code look? Are you using it for `<img>` or for a `background-image`?

Comment: Added it in my comments.

Comment: Now, it's working.  I have no clue what happened.  :/

Comment: @ThomasHutton do you have the same issue, when you replace the URL with http://svgur.com/i/xf.svg ?
Edit: Oh lol, yeah there are some weird issues. But good that it works now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137907/discussion-between-thomas-hutton-and-reza-saadati).

Comment: hi i have same porblem .. it looks ok i open in a new tab .. but in tag <img > doesn't work (i put height and width but nothing) .. and if svg are not  inside a tag image but in a svg tag they works!!

Comment: I used `min-height: 35px;` and `min-width: 35px;`, so that I don't actually ahve to make the width and height static, and is there only to fix the display issue. The pixel value should be something smaller than the smallest possible width/height of you SVG (e.g. on a very small screen), but something that makes it work with you SVG. For me the amgic value was 35px.

Answer (score 2):

Just you can do from the CSS class, only need to add SVG container width as below code:

```
.your-logo{width:300px;}
```

You can set your width as your require.